# Is there a way to discriminate a union type without doing an if statement?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to assert a discriminated union without doing an if statement?

```js
export type Maybe<T> = T | null | undefined;

export type Scalars = {
    String: string;
    GUID: string;
    DateTime: string;
};

export type Project = Node & {
    __typename?: 'Project';
    id: Scalars['GUID'];
    name: Scalars['String'];
    description?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
    logoUrl?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
    createdAt: Scalars['DateTime'];
    updatedAt: Scalars['DateTime'];
};

export type GetProjectForProjectDetailPageQuery = { __typename?: 'Query' } & {
    node?: Maybe<
        | { __typename?: 'Employee' }
        | { __typename?: 'JobTitle' }
        | ({ __typename?: 'Project' } & Pick<Project, 'id' | 'name' | 'description' | 'logoUrl' | 'updatedAt'>)
    >;
};

// Is there a way to assert the typename is Project without doing an if statement?
const x: GetProjectForProjectDetailPageQuery = {};

// Only picks up __typename field
x.node

// Works but requires an if statement. I'd like to eliminate the if statement.
if(x.node?.__typename === 'Project') {
    x.node.id    
    x.node.name     
    x.node.description    
    x.node.logoUrl    
}
```

Some context:

The above types are generated by GraphQL Code Generator so I don't have control over the types generated, I'm interested in the fields together with the `Project` `__typename` and I know ahead that this will always be the case so I was wondering if there's a way to eliminate the if statement to discriminate the union.

Edit:

Played with @jcalz suggestions and came up with this in the [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=47&ssc=64&pln=47&pc=71#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-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-6AdyIECsKorihMWmzHmxldImvZAA) but not quite there yet.

Would like to get type safety for the generic `T` that's derived from `N`'s `__typename` field if that's possible...

```js
// I'd like the generic T here to pickup possible values from the __typename field of generic N
type ExtractNode<N, T extends string> = Extract<NonNullable<N>, { __typename?: T }>

// What I expect
const node = {
    id: 'yes'
} as ExtractNode<GetProjectForProjectDetailPageQuery['node'], 'Project'>;
```

Comment: Can you remove  `| { __typename?: 'Employee' } | { __typename?: 'JobTitle' }` from the GetProjectForProjectDetailPageQuery type?

Comment: @Will No, the types are generated by GraphQL Code Generator so I have no control over the types.

Comment: Its not possible, you are saying you work with a type which can be one o three possible, you cannot just use it in a type safe way without if. You can make type assertion but it will be type unsafe

Comment: Does [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/uskidp?file=index.ts) meet your needs? If so, I'll write up the answer. If not, please let me know what the issue is and/or modify the question to explain more.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz Thanks. It does, however this looks rather way longer to type/read than an if statement haha. Do you think there's a much shorter way of doing it?

Comment: Is "no longer than an if statement" a requirement?  If so I doubt you'll find something better than `if (!x.node || x.node.__typename !== "Project") throw new Error();`.  Is "no runtime impact" a requirement?  If so then you need to come up with a name for your narrowed type and assert it in probably multiple places, which will end up being quite verbose.

Comment: @jcalz No, none of those are a hard requirement. Was wondering if there's a no runtime impact shorter way of doing it. I added an edit, I think that'd be the best approach for my case to shorten this. Is it possible to get type safety for the generic T?

Comment: Like `type ExtractNode<N extends { __typename?: string } | undefined | null, T extends NonNullable<NonNullable<N>["__typename"]>> =Extract<NonNullable<N>, { __typename?: T }>` maybe?  Not sure if that's what you're looking for.  At some point I'd like to write up an answer to this; let me know if you have any outstanding issues.

Comment: @jcalz awesome, that's exactly what I wanted! Yes please write that as an answer.